# How can I set VS Code to suggest 'assets' instead of 'src/assets' for img src in Angular HTML templates?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, path, autocomplete, intellisense

VsCode suggestion in a html template is starting from src, and angular is configured to resolve from
assets directly.

```
      <!-- vscode suggestion -->
      <img src="/src/assets/theme-change-icon.png" alt="" />
      <!-- works in build but vscode cant resolve it  -->
      <img src="assets/theme-change-icon.png" alt="" />

"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
```

}

```
      "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/verso-mart",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
```

I have tried to change the baseUrl in tsconfig.json to ./src and same in the angular.json and did not change anything. Should it not supose to be so the autocompletion understand tsconfig.json and angular.json and autcomplete based on it? Is this a bug?

1. Its there a way to change so it will understand the project structure and start autcomplete from assets?
2. What will be a solution in this case.